# Creative and Objective Mismatch while creating Carousal Ad by using Marketing API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, carousel, facebook-marketing-api

I'm creating Carousel Ad via marketing API. During the Ad creation Facebook through "Creative and Objective Mis-match" error. However, Campaign and Adset are successfully creating.

I have changed the objective as per Facebook documentation. I tried multiple combinations but got errors. e.g: "Billing event invalid for optimisation goal, Creative and Objective Mismatch, Invalid Creative for Objective"
[Doc_link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/validation/#objective_creative)

```
res = ad_account.ads.create({
  status: 'ACTIVE',
  name:  ' SDK',
adset_id: adset.id,
creative: {
  object_story_spec: {
  page_id: fb_page_id,
  link_data: { 
  child_attachments: [
     { 
     description: "$8.99", 
     image_hash: "1ea34798e1ba00ffaab318dc", 
     link: "www.facebook.com", 
     name: "Product 1", 
     video_id: "42920500794",
    call_to_action: {
    type: "LEARN_MORE",
    value: {
    link: "www.facebook.com"
        }
      }
    }, 
    { 
    description: "$9.99", 
    image_hash: "8299deb1e053f7601c4f99f44", 
    link: "www.facebook.com", 
    name: "Product 2", 
    video_id: "378442876",
    call_to_action: {
    type: "LEARN_MORE",
    value: {
    link: "www.facebook.com"
        }
      }
    }, 
        ],
    :link => "www.facebook.com",
     },                         
    }
       }
  })
```

I need to create a complete carousel ad by using marketing API.

Answer (score 0):

Here are changes and restrictions about new Campaign objectives. So when I added destination_type to ad_set and additional params like `optimization_goal` or `promoted_object` (depends on destination type) - it fixed this error.

Added in `adsets` and It's Work for me:

```
destination_type: "ON_POST",
optimization_goal: "REACH"
```

Do you still have issues? Please check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/710768544527183/)